# Is it possible to make an extension method aware of the syntax it is called by?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

*Edit: The collective "Hey stupid" was a very nice reminder to re-think my original problem. My curiosity still stands on the subject so I've edited out the bad idea bits.*

Given an extension method:

```
public static class Util {
  public static string Triple<T>(this T t) { 
    var builder = new StringBuilder(); 
    foreach (char c in t.ToString()) {
      builder.Append(c, 3);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
  }
}
```

I know I can call this method using either the instance member syntax,i.e. `foo.Triple()`, or with static method syntax, `Util.Triple(foo)`. Do I have a way to make the extension method aware of in which manner it is called? Consider (not valid C#):

```
public static class Util {
    public static string Triple<T>(this T t) { 
      if (calledStatic) {
        // do something if called by static syntax
      } else {
        // do something if not called by static syntax
      }
      var builder = new StringBuilder(); 
      foreach (char c in t.ToString()) {
        builder.Append(c, 3);
      }
      return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've checked the C# language specification, specifically regarding extension methods, SO questions, and am at a loss.

Bottom line version: *Can I make an extension method aware of the manner in which it is called?*

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Also, throwing NullReferenceException is rarely the right thing to do.

Comment: Going to take a punt on "no" here, as my guess is that they both compile down to a static invocation anyway.

Comment: Please reconsider your approach. Chances are you're attempting something that doesn't even make sense to begin with.

Comment: As @HighCore says, you might get more out of posting a question about the actual problem you're trying to solve, here, as this is clearly not the right way to go about whatever you're trying to do. It looks like you're just trying to hide the fact that the `this T t` parameter exists if it's called as an extension method. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Appearance's sake but I'm quickly reconsidering, I figured it would make more sense for `foo.Triple()` to throw a `NullReferenceException` atleast on the surface, but if it compiles down to `Util.Triple(foo)`, it seems like a bad idea

Comment: Throwing a `NullReferenceException` is always a bad idea. All it does is obscure the problem.

Comment: The collective "Hey stupid" was a very nice reminder to re-think my original problem. My curiosity still stands on the subject so I've edited out the bad idea bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't. Compiler changes your extension method instance-like call to static method call anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. Extension methods are just "compiler magic", the compiled version of `foo.Triple()` will look like `Util.Triple(foo)` anyway.